# Linear model convergence changes when column orders is changed

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When I change the order of the columns (features order) in the `SciKit` linear models with regularization, I get different scores. I have tested this with `ElasticNet` and `Lasso`. I am using `scikit-learn==0.23.1`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'col2': [16, 32, 64, 12, 5, 256],
    'col3': [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 11],
    'out': [40, 5, 60, 7, 9, 100]})

print(df)
X_df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
y_df = df['out']
regr = linear_model.ElasticNet(alpha=0.1, random_state=0)

regr.fit(X_df, y_df)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_df)
print("R2:", regr.score(X_df, y_df))
print("MSE:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_df, y_pred))

# change the order to: [col2, col1, col3]
first_cols = ['col2']
cols = first_cols.copy()
for c in X_df.columns:
    if c not in cols:
        cols.append(c)
X_df = X_df[cols]

regr.fit(X_df, y_df)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_df)
print("\nReorder:")
print("R2:", regr.score(X_df, y_df))
print("MSE:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_df, y_pred))
```

The output of the above is:

```
col1  col2  col3  out
0     1    16     7   40
1     2    32     8    5
2     3    64     9   60
3     4    12    10    7
4     5     5    12    9
5     6   256    11  100
R2: 0.8277462579081043
MSE: 207.13034003933535

Reorder:
R2: 0.8277586094134455
MSE: 207.11548769725997
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is because of the `tol` param.

From Documentation:

> tol : float, default=1e-4
>
> The tolerance for the optimization: if the updates are
> smaller than `tol`, the optimization code checks the
> dual gap for optimality and continues until it is smaller
> than `tol`.

Just add get the level of precision you want add `tol=1e-12` in both cases.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'col2': [16, 32, 64, 12, 5, 256],
    'col3': [7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 11],
    'out': [40, 5, 60, 7, 9, 100]})

# print(df)
X_df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
y_df = df['out']
regr = linear_model.ElasticNet(alpha=0.1, random_state=0, tol=1e-12)

regr.fit(X_df, y_df)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_df)
print(regr.coef_)
print("R2:", regr.score(X_df, y_df))
print("MSE:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_df, y_pred))

# change the order to: [col2, col1, col3]
first_cols = ['col2']
cols = first_cols.copy()
for c in X_df.columns:
    if c not in cols:
        cols.append(c)
X_df = X_df[cols]


regr = linear_model.ElasticNet(alpha=0.1, random_state=0, tol=1e-12)
regr.fit(X_df, y_df)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_df)
print("\nReorder:")
print(regr.coef_)
print("R2:", regr.score(X_df, y_df))
print("MSE:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_df, y_pred))
```

```
[-8.92519779  0.42980208  3.59812779]
R2: 0.8277593357239204
MSE: 207.11461432908925

Reorder:
[ 0.42980208 -8.92519779  3.59812779]
R2: 0.8277593357240851
MSE: 207.11461432889112
```

Comment: Great, thanks! So, AFAIU, the optimization continues until the gap between the primal and dual solutions become smaller than `tol`. right? do you have more info to add?

Comment: Nothing much. This tol will affect the values of coef which in turn changes your score

Answer (score -1):

Changing column order affects order of operations during training. In ideal world it won't matter, but because of precision loss in floating point numbers, you may get slightly different values just from changing column order.

Comment: I'd say 207.11 vs 207.13 in this small example is quite significant. It should not happen!

Comment: Well, for this case it may affect results more because your features are collinear: col1 and col2 look correlated with each other. It will cause higher variance in results.